# Deploy Glassfish : V3 cannot process this command at this time, please wait

Tags: jenkins, glassfish-3

I 'm trying to deploy my ear with Jenkins on my Glassfish server with the following command :

`nohup /home/hadrienmp/bin/glassfish3/bin/asadmin deploy --force  metier-ear.ear > Output.out 2> Error.err < /dev/null &`

Sometimes it works but most of the time I get the following error message : 'V3 cannot process this command at this time, please wait'.

My Glassfish server hosts webservices that are used by other developers. I don't know if it can prevent Glassfish from deploying my ear correctly.

Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured it out. I have 4 projects that depend on each other to deploy every night. What each build did was restart the Glassfish after the deploy to avoid any memory issue.

I think that the builds run too quickly for the Glassfish to have fully restarted. To fix this I just run my 4 builds 30 minutes apart from each other.